# sheet Map 0 have no Rows in excelize

Tags: go, excelize

Helo everyone need your help.

I had one file that I get from daily report download with `xlsx` extension.
Then I want to insert to `MongoDB` for analytic cause per day can be 100K rows, and I use golang with excelize to extract excel data then insert them to mongoDB, there is the problem :

When I `GetRows("Sheet 1")` the result is 0 and when I check the sheet with `GetSeetMap()` result is `[0:Sheet 1]` and it is still 0 rows.

But when I renamed sheet name (ie: rename to `another Sheet`) and I check the sheet map it change to `[1:another Sheet]` and rows detected when the sheet map key is 1, how to fix this?

Thanks for advance

Comment: Looks like a question for the [project's issue tracker](https://github.com/qax-os/excelize/issues), not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it shouldn't be "Sheet1"  (i.e. without a space)?

Comment: yeah, i try with sheet name "Sheet1" also but not work, and when i call ```GetSeetMap()``` its give ```[0:Sheet 1]``` thats mean using space